# JPA Query Entity not mapped error

Tags: java, jpa, hql, jpql

Testing is not passing in the following code. Debugging shows the error is in the creation of the query.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Catalog is not mapped [SELECT c FROM Catalog c WHERE c.name = :name]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1347)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eb_catalog", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name"))
public class Catalog implements ICatalog, Serializable {
```

and the query itself:

```
TypedQuery<Catalog> query = em.createQuery(
"SELECT c FROM Catalog c WHERE c.name = :name", Catalog.class)
.setParameter("name", catName);
```

CTRL + click on Catalog is opening the entity, so the name matches the entity in the query.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may have forgotten to map your entity class in the `persistence.xml`.
Take a look :)